# Image processing - Service locator pattern & Container of dependencies

Tags: object-oriented, c, inversion-of-control, ioc-containers, service-locator

As per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection),

> A **dependency** is an object that can be used (as a service).

---

[here](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/tree/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3) is the OOP paradigm using C syntax that address 4 roles, shown below.

## 1) interface (`handlers.h`)

```
typedef struct {
    int (*canHandle) (char *);
    int (*drawImage)(char *);
    int (*savefile)(char *);
}imageHandler;
```

---

## 2) Take one Dependency (`gifhandler.c`)

```
imageHandler gifhandler = {
    gif_canHandle,
    gif_drawImage,
    gif_savefile
};
```

---

## 3) Dependency container (dealt by `config.c`)

```
//gifhandler.c - dependency 
int _init(){
    printf(" registering gifhandler \n");
    reg_handler(&gifhandler);
    return 0;
}

//config.c
imageHandler *imagehandlers[10];
int reg_handler(imageHandler *ih){
// we need to perform checks here.
    imagehandlers[libs] = ih;
    libs++;
    return TRUE;
}
// config.c
int init_handlers(){
    .....
    soptr = dlopen(so_name,RTLD_NOW);
    ....
}
```

---

## 4) Client - Service locator (`UI.C`)

```
// UI.C
switch(choice){
        case 1:
            vdrawImage(filename);   
            break;
        case 2:
            vsavefile(filename);
            break;
}
// viml.c
int vdrawImage(char *filename){
    ...
    handleno = find_handler(filename);
    ...
    ih=imagehandlers[handleno];
    ih->drawImage(filename);    
    return FALSE;       
}
// viml.c
int vsavefile(char *newfilename ){
    ...
    handleno = find_handler(newfilename);
    ...
    ih=imagehandlers[handleno];
    ih->savefile(newfilename); 
}
```

---

1) To add new dependency(`libxyzhandl.so.1`) in Dependency container, it just requires adding a new entry in `config.txt` **configurable**, as shown below,

> **config.txt**
>
> `./libgifhandl.so.1`
>
> `./libtiffhandl.so.1`

2) New service provided by `./libxyzhandl.so.1`, will be contained by Dependency container  **without re-compilation** of application.

3) Testing of complete application is **not required**, except source code of `libxyzhandl.so`.

So, if `config.txt` goes empty, then, application does nothing, except saying, `We cannot handle this kind of files`, shown [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/blob/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3/VIML.C#L25), for any input(image file).

Below is the visualisation of call flow,

### [image]

**Question:**

Can this *dependency container* be called an *IOC container*?

Comment: Sorry, I still can't say I see how `imageHandler` is constructed. Can you show me the line of code where it's happening?

Comment: @CandiedOrange Now, you should see that in query. Query edited. Hope it clarifies

Comment: if `imagehandlers[10]` is your construction code I need to know where that is and what else is going on there. I need context.

Comment: @CandiedOrange `extern imageHandler *imagehandlers[];` in `handlers.h`, `imagehandlers` is array of structure of pointers(vtable). Each element of array, houses behavior code

Comment: You've shown the dependency that get's constructed: `imageHandlers`. You've shown the client that uses the dependency: `reg_handler`. You haven't shown the injector that constructs and passes the dependency to the client. You've only shown the line of code that does the construction `imagehandlers[10]`. I need to see where that line lives.

Comment: `_init()` lives in `gifhandler.c` or `tiffhandler.c`(Behavior code)

Comment: You're making it sound like the dependency `gifhandler` injects itself. Which is completely wrong.

Comment: @CandiedOrange `./libgifHandler.so` injects itself, when `app` runs `dlopen()` in `init_handlers()`/`config.c`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62682/discussion-between-candiedorange-and-overexchange).

Comment: You have not explained why dependency injection is needed.

Comment: @FrankHileman Query edited

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to any definition of dependency injection. Long before this term became popular, image processing frameworks and applications used the exact same thing, called plug-ins. It is not always necessary to have a configuration file. Just having a file present in a directory (a library) with the correct types inside is usually enough for it to be dynamically loaded, and an instance installed in the application or framework.

Comment: @FrankHileman Are my implementations thread safe? What if client invokes implementation on a thread? My implementation is an element in array of Structure of function pointers.

Comment: It depends on how you initialize the array. If you do it before anything else runs, and you make everything read-only (immutable), then it will be safe to use on other threads, after initialization. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @FrankHileman Can I call it IOC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of the client code you've posted, this is *not* dependency injection.  Your client references a statically-defined collection of objects and requests one that matches certain criteria, which is much more similar to the [Service Locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) than Dependency Injection.  That said, they are two similar patterns that achieve a number of the same goals.  The only real difference is that wouldn't be possible for your application to have, for example, two different invocations of `vdrawImage` or `vsavefile` that use a different handler object for the same file type (which could be beneficial for unit testing, for example), while traditional dependency injection has a little more overhead but can achieve this level of configuration.

Comment: 1) Statically defined collection?  Dependencies are available at runtime. 2) That matching criteria is vtable logic, as C does not support polymorphism, as a language feature.

Comment: By statically defined I mean the same instance is shared between all invocations. You can't have one set of objects in one part of your program and a different set in another part, because there's only a single pointer to the dependencies shared by all clients. In a dependency injection system, each client gets their own copy of the pointer so that they can have a different dependency if necessary.

Comment: For every `vdrawImage(filename)` we get corresponding dependency(`handleno = find_handler(filename);`), based on the `filename` passed to `vdrawImage()`. Isn't it?

Comment: What if you want two different calls to `vdrawImage("test.png")` to use a different implementation of your handler object? They both call the same `file_handler` function that pulls the same object out of global data.  This is the main distinction between dependency injection and the service locator pattern. Service locators are great for many things, but they're hard to write unit tests against, because very often different tests want to use different mock implementations in otherwise indistinguishable calls to the locator.

Comment: Can this dependency container be called as IOC container?

Answer (score 4):

> Dependency injection **can** be used to externalize a system's configuration details into configuration files

If you're doing simple reference passing you can do your configuration in main (or whatever your composition root is). That's certainly Dependency Injection.  Using a configuration file that doesn't need to be compiled to create the object graph is optional.

The goal in either case is to have a clear separation between behavior code and construction code.

I can't really tell if you're meeting this goal because I don't see where `imageHandler` is being constructed. All I know is that it doesn't look like `reg_handler` is constructing it. Which if `reg_handler` holds behavior code, is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why this discussion goes in divergent directions, with different people giving different answers.

Dependency Injection describes a technique in **object oriented programming** (OOP). Meanwhile, your sample code isn't OOP.

The goal of Dependency Injection is to have flexibility - to allow a piece of client code to work with a choice of different service implementations, without requiring the client code to be recompiled. To this end, your non-OOP sample code seems to have the same kind of flexibility, even though it is non-OOP.

As noted by others, your code contains some characteristics of service locator, plugin system, and IoC container configuration using configuration files.

Though, because your sample code is non-OOP, programmers who are deep into OOP can't use their rules-of-thumb to judge whether your code fits a certain OOP pattern.

With respect to Dependency Injection, OOP programmers will ask these questions:

1. Are there different service implementations? (e.g. S1, S2, S3, ...)
2. Do these service implementations implement the same interface (I)? Or do they all derive from the same abstract base class (S)?
3. Does the client (application code) use the service implementation strictly in accordance with the interface (via I or S)?
4. Is the client code encapsulated into an object (C)?
5. When the client object (C) is initializing (e.g. in the constructor, or shortly after having been constructed), does it allow the user of this object (the owner of C, therefore not part of C but at a higher command level) to specify which service implementation to use, by passing in an instance of that implementation?

Condition #5 is the uniquely-identifying characteristic of dependency injection. For OOP programmers, they will jump to condition #5 without verifying conditions #1 - #4. It is because OOP programmers took these for granted. Therefore, OOP programmers will ask to see the constructor or the property-setters of the client object (C). Your code doesn't have these.

When applying these conditions to your sample code, the results are:

1. Yes
2. Yes. However, the "interface" is not based on OOP-style interface or abstract base class. Instead, it is based on C-style function pointers.
3. Yes.
4. No. There is an "application" that runs a menu-driven application loop.
5. Not applicable. The application code is already at the highest command level; there is no other "code". In some sense, the only higher command level is the (human) user who gives keyboard input to the program.

---

**Edited:** Suppose we stretch the definition of OOP to cover C-style function pointers and explicit vtables. Here is my response:

The essence of Dependency Injection is that, after you have obtained a pointer to an `imagehandler`, as in:

```
// ih is a pointer to a struct that contains three function pointers
ih = imagehandlers[handleno];
```

that you have other functions that **accepts** the `ih` pointer as a function parameter (input argument). This is the essence.

Comment: Code has implemented polymorphism(vtable). Which aspect of OOP is missing?  Encapsulation is not required, as there are no invariants to maintain.

Comment: @overexchange: Your code is perfectly fine. I just try to explain why other people gives different answers. Also, I am sure that there will be other programmers who will say that DI is not applicable to non-OOP code, therefore your code example isn't a valid showcase of DI. (i.e. it gets down into philosophical arguments.)

Comment: @overexchange It also depends on what your ultimate goal is. If your ultimate goal is to build an image-handling application that supports different image formats, then I think your code is fine. However, if you are looking for (or constructing) a code example that teaches people what is DI and what is not DI, then it will be a bad example, because a good example for DI should have both the services and the client(s) as objects.

Comment: @overexchange I edited my answer.

Comment: Given the wiki definition, goal is to satisfy it, with the implementation, irrespective of paradigm used(OOP or whatever). DI has nothing to do with OOP paradigm. If class based syntax dies, then DI will still exist.

Comment: Actually, dependency injection can be used without true OO languages, just as most other techniques.

Comment: @FrankHileman I partly agree with that, but then how would you answer the question of "does it use constructor injection or property injection"? In the OP's code sample, it would be "static injection", injected into a global variable, something OOP programmers wouldn't accept. Btw my point is not to get religious about paradigms; it's just that it wouldn't meet the expectation of some programmers, i.e. there will be people who disagree.

Comment: @rwong While global variables are not allowed in many OO languages, static fields for example in .net, accessed publicly or modified via side effects globally, have all the same problems. The problem with this question is the emphasis on dependency injection, like you said. It doesn't matter whether it is dependency injection or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, this is more in line with the Open/Closed principle.  Dependency injection abstracts common dependencies so that the implementation of the abstract dependency doesn't matter and is "injected" into the process, by constructor or property injection.

Comment: `reg_handler()` in `config.c`is the constructor for `extern imageHandler *imagehandlers[];` declared in `handlers.h`.

Comment: I'm not a c programmer, but it seems this code is designed explicitly to import one or more implementations and loading them dynamically.  What would happen if the file were empty?  Is your program dependent upon them?

Comment: If `config.txt` is empty, then, `printf(" We cannot handle this kind of files\n");` executes, shown [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/blob/master/Dependency_Injection/VIML.C#L25)
So, if `config.txt` is empty, then application cannot support any image file as there is no corresponding service injected, on restart of my application ), for any input(image file) by user. So, if config.txt is empty, then application cannot support any image file as there is no corresponding service injected, on restart of my application

Comment: If that's the purpose of the app, and nothing else gets done without a handler in the config file, then it could be considered dependency injection.  After all, this is similar to the methods used by some IoC containers, where dependencies can be registered in config files.